# Colouring text doen't work in newcommand definition

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, text-decorations, todonotes, changes

I am trying to define a new \note command based on todonotes and changes packages but I'm having troubles with the optional selected text styling. I want it to be coloured based on the changes ID assigned colour.

Heres the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[markup=underlined]{changes}
\usepackage[]{todonotes}

\definechangesauthor[color=BrickRed]{MyName}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\note}[2][]{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\note@i[{#1}]{#2}}{\note@i[{#1}]{#2}[{}]}%
}
\def\note@i[#1]#2[#3]{%
  \todo[color=Changes@Color#1!20,size=\scriptsize]{#1: \emph{#2}} %
  \textcolor{Changes@Color#1}{#3} %
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit \note{Just a note without selected text and
without author.} amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat.\note[MyName]{My comment}{Proin a lectus vestibulum, mollis eros 
id, vehicula mauris.} Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
cupidatat \note[MyName]{My other comment without text selectd.}non 
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est \note{Some 
comment about some selected text.}{laborum}

\end{document}
```

The result is looking like this:
[image]

but I want the text "Proin a lectus vestibulum, mollis eros id, vehicula mauris." to be coloured BrickRed.

PS! I should mention that I used [this package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newcommand) to generate the new command like so:

```
$ python newcommand.py 
% Prototype: MACRO notee OPT[#1={}] #2 OPT[#3={}]
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\notee}[2][]{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\notee@i[{#1}]{#2}}{\notee@i[{#1}]{#2}[{}]}%
}

\def\notee@i[#1]#2[#3]{%
  % Put your code here.
  % You can refer to the arguments as #1 through #3.
}
\makeatother
```

## Solution

Thanks to @egreg! With a bit of tweaking I ended up with the result I was looking for!

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\note}{omo}{%
  % #1 (optional) = addition to Changes@color
  % #2 text for \todo
  % #3 (optional) text for the change%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {
        \todo[color=Changes@Color#1!20,size=\scriptsize]{#1: \emph{#2}}
        \IfValueT{#3}{\textcolor{Changes@Color#1}{#3}}
    }%
    {
        \todo[color=Changes@Color!20,size=\scriptsize]{\emph{#2}}
        \IfValueT{#3}{\textcolor{Changes@Color}{#3}}
    }%
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nice example!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the defined syntax, `Proin...` should be in brackets:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[markup=underlined]{changes}
\usepackage[]{todonotes}

\definechangesauthor[color=BrickRed]{MyName}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\note}[2][]{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\note@i[{#1}]{#2}}{\note@i[{#1}]{#2}[{}]}%
}
\def\note@i[#1]#2[#3]{%
  \todo[color=Changes@Color#1!20,size=\scriptsize]{#1: \emph{#2}}%
  \textcolor{Changes@Color#1}{#3}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit \note{Just a note without selected text and
without author.} amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat.\note[MyName]{My comment}[Proin a lectus vestibulum, mollis eros 
id, vehicula mauris.] Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
cupidatat \note[MyName]{My other comment without text selectd.}non 
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est \note{Some 
comment about some selected text.}{laborum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A perhaps more friendly way to define `\note` with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[markup=underlined]{changes}
\usepackage[]{todonotes}
\usepackage{xparse}

\definechangesauthor[color=BrickRed]{MyName}

\NewDocumentCommand{\note}{O{}mo}{%
  % #1 (optional) = addition to Changes@color
  % #2 text for \todo
  % #3 (optional) text for the change
  \todo[color=Changes@Color#1!20,size=\scriptsize]{#1: \emph{#2}}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{\textcolor{Changes@Color#1}{#3}}%
}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit \note{Just a note without selected text and
without author.} amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat.\note[MyName]{My comment}[Proin a lectus vestibulum, mollis eros 
id, vehicula mauris.] Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
cupidatat \note[MyName]{My other comment without text selectd.}non 
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est \note{Some 
comment about some selected text.}{laborum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @sandert I added a better way to define `\note`.

Comment: Please look at my modified solution. I thought I had it but there's a catch. If I set the todonotes package 'disable' option and changes package 'final' option then the text is still coloured. I dont want that :(

Comment: @sandert That's a completely different problem.

Comment: Should I make an another question then? :)

Comment: @sandert I'd say so

Comment: Made another question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410229/disabling-changes-and-todonotes-packages-text-is-still-being-coloured